# Easy way to split 'from:' line containing full name, commend, and email address using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any easy way (without pandas) to split this:

'First Last (id_192743918) <192743918@example.com>'

Into this:

```
results = {
    'name': 'First Last',
    'comment': 'id_192743918',
    'email': '192743918@example.com',
}
```

I can do this with a few splits, but I'm sure there has be a graceful method to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along this way can do it:

```
import re 
st = 'First Last (id_192743918) <192743918@example.com>'
# split the string by ( or ) 
l = re.split(r'\(|\)', st)
# strip whitespaces and replace < or > by empty space '' 
l = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r'<|>','', x.strip()),l))

results = {
    'name': l[0],
    'comment': l[1],
    'email': l[2],
}
```

Comment: I liked all the answers, but this one is the clearest to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @tazzytazzy you are welcome :). I encourage you to vote up the other answers as well, to motivate people to continue providing help on Stackoverflow :). I voted them up :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use regex for this.  In the following code, I combine regex with a dictionary comprehension to generate your dictionary quickly.

```
import re

string = "First Last (id_192743918) <192743918@example.com>"
print({['name','comment','email'][i]:g for i,g in enumerate(re.search("(\w+ \w+) \((.*?)\) <(.*?)>", string).groups())})
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'First Last', 'comment': 'id_192743918', 'email': '192743918@example.com'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
line = 'First Last (id_192743918) <192743918@example.com>'

l = line.split()

result = {'name': l[0]+' '+l[1], 'comment':l[2][1:-1], 'email':l[3][1:-1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another re example:

```
text='First Last (id_192743918) <192743918@example.com>'

matches=re.findall("(^.*)\((.*)\).*<(.*)>", text)[0]

result={"name":matches[0].strip(),
        "comment":matches[1].strip(),
        "email":matches[2].strip()}
```